# Different animations on different routes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I want to make slide animations between pages. I made basic slide animation from right to left, like this: [AngularJS animation examples](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1)

But for the different routes, i want different animations (from right to left, or from left to right).
I found some solutions for older versions of angularjs. I think there must be an easy way to do it now, when animations is a part of angular. Where can i find some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom property for each route specifying the animation class to use:

```
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {
  templateUrl: 'view1.html',
  controller: 'View1Controller',
  animation: 'from-left'
});

$routeProvider.when('/view2', {
  templateUrl: 'view2.html',
  controller: 'View2Controller',
  animation: 'from-right'
});
```

Then add a directive that retrieves the current route's animation and adds it to the element:

```
app.directive('viewAnimation', function ($route) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var animation = $route.current.animation;
      if (animation) element.addClass(animation);
    }
  };
});
```

Put the directive on the same element that contains the ngView directive:

```
<body ng-view view-animation></body>
```

Might need some tweaks depending on your use case, but should hopefully be a good start.

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/jJgWoQ9lCPonmx5KmSJ6?p=preview